# Code Coverage and Blame

Tags: svn, version-control, code-coverage, ncover

Has anyone seen a tool that will integrate code coverage results with SCM/VCS to attribute untested lines of code to developers?
For example, is there a tool that will take NCover's Coverage.Xml, combine it with SVN blame, and produce a report that tells me things like developer who commits most untested code?

Answer (score 1):

not done this but [team city](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/code_quality.html) offers some facilities along those lines...

Answer (score 1):

I use CC.NET (ccnet.thoughtworks.com/) and NANT to evaluate code coverage of my applications. By default it is not tied to the developers commits but I think that it would not be difficult to create a NANT Task that do it.